# Get teams I am member of

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to retrieve all teams in a specific TFS team project where I am member. Is this possible with the REST Api?

I know that you can fetch all teams, for each team the members and then sort all teams out where I am not a member.

Is it possible to just fetch the teams that I am a member of?

Comment: Like football teams?

Comment: It is not clear what teams you are talking about. Consider specifying what REST endpoint is being discussed here.

Comment: TFS Teams.the tag makes that clear. There's only one sort of teams in TFS.

Comment: There's a WEB API for it: `https://{ACCOUNT}.visualstudio.com/_api/_identity/ReadGroupMembers?__v=5&scope={USERGUID}&readMembers=false`, but that doesn't seem to be supported for external calls and is protected by a Cross Site Scripting Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For REST API, it's **impossible** to directly fetch the teams that a specific be a member of.

You could only get all teams within the project that the authenticated user has access to. Then get a list of identity references for the team's members. At last fetch the teams that you are a member of.

Related API and code sample please refer this link [Teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-teams-members).

Unless that the teams you are not the member of , you **also don't have the corresponding permission to access it**. You could simply use below Rest API, since the API will get all teams within the project that **the authenticated user has access to**.

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{project}/teams?api-version={version}[&$top={integer}&$skip={integer}]
```